# Is it a compact subset of whole space?

Tags: general-topology

Recently, I met a problem as the following:
Suppose $X$ is a topological space. If $B$ is a compact subset of $X$, $A$  is a compact subset of $B$, is  $A$   a compact subset of $X$?

I will appreciate it if someone can give me some hints .

Comment: What definition do you know? The finite subcover of an open cover property?

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof  the finite subcover of an open cover property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ be an open cover of $A$ by open subsets of $X$. By the definition of the topology on $B$, $(U_i \cap B)_{i \in I}$ is an open cover of $A$ by open subsets of $B$. Since $A$ is compact in $B$, this open cover of $A$ admits a finite subcover $(U_i \cap B)_{i \in F}$. It follows that $(U_i)_{i \in F}$ is a finite cover of $A$. Thus $A$ is compact in $X$. Note that the hypothesis that $B$ is compact is useless.

Comment: @Pin  Thanks a lot!  it is very helpful to me.

Comment: You're welcome. I noticed that you asked already several questions, but you never accepted any answer. Are you aware that you can [upvote an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) and you can also [accept](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) it?

Comment: @Pin sorry, I do not know that I should select one answer  to accept . Thank you tell me that.

Answer (score 1):

The subspace topology is the set of all intersections of open sets from the topology on $X$ with the set $B$.

Thus if you have an open cover of $A$ in $X$, by taking intersections with $B$ it gives rise to an open cover in $B$.  Take a finite subcover, by compactness in $B$.  Each element of the subcover comes from an element of $X$. Take such an element.  Thus we get a finite subcover in $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is true. It follows from the definition of compact that, for a subspace, being compact doesn't depend upon the larger space.

Comment: @Santos  I think it is right. Just a little feel confused about it.

Comment: In order to determine whether a subspace is compact, all you need to know is the list of all open sets *of that subspace *. What lies outside the subspace doesn't matter.